# Can Mac system updates recover accidentally deleted kernel files?

Tags: software-update, macos

We commonly know that system updates will fix the kernel defects that have been discovered or not previously disclosed, to make the OS more secure.

However, what if I accidentally deleted some kernel files, will a new system update recovers the kernel files I deleted?

Comment: Do you precisely know which kernel files you accidentally removed?

Comment: Actually, I am learning Operating System course, this question just came in my mind. I am thinking about in case kernel is compromised, how kernel can be recovered. @danielAzuelos

Comment: This is a pretty good and difficult question. I tried to answer it on this other question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/177055/22003 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System updates (on any system) only modify **targeted** files which need improvment or removal.

They might **accidentally** repair a file you have damaged.
They might also **accidentally** damage a file you have fixed. But this isn't their target.

A **full install** will of course reinstall any file you removed.

Comment: How about prestigious anti-virus software? Will that recover the kernels (recover modified kernel files), maybe?

Comment: Not at all! This is none of their business. They don't have a database of all the correct versions of kernel files. The operating system editors have already some difficulties to maintain such a database due to the sustained rythm at which they blitz new versions and fixes.

Comment: So, if my kernel is compromised, the only option is to back up the whole data, and reinstalled the operating system?

Comment: If your kernel is compromised, don't do any backup :(.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely not. They may be a completely new file, but in general updates are just patches to the already existing file.